# Variable undefined when using jquery ajax in expressjs

Tags: jquery, ajax, express, undefined

I have admin login form in expressjs, then post the variable using ajax. On the server side I have post function but it always ends up undefined on the client side. Please help me, how to authenticate the variable.

This is the login form:

```html
 <body>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="profile">
          <button class="profile__avatar" id="btn_avatar">
            <img src="/images/avatar.png" alt="Avatar" />
          </button>
        <div class="profile__form">
          <div class="profile__fields">
          <h3 class="text-center">Welcome Admin Lelang</h3>
            <form>
              <div class="fields">
                <input type="text" class="input" required-pattern=.*\S.* id="username" placeholder="Username" />
                <label class="label" for="fieldUsername">Username</label>
              </div>
              <div class="fields">
                <input type="password" class="input" required-pattern=.*\S.* id="password" placeholder="password" />
                <label class="label" for="fieldPassword">Password</label>
              </div>
              <div class="alert alert-warning" id="warning">
                <em class="fa fa-lg fa-warning">&nbsp;</em>Peringatan, username atau password salah 
              </div>
              <div class="profile__footer">
                <center>
                  <button class="btn" id="btn-submit">LOG IN</button>
                </center>
              </div>
            </form>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src = "/javascripts/admin/login.js"></script>
  </body>
```

This is the ajax:

```js
//===================Fungsi btn submit login===================///
$(function(){
  $('#btn-submit').click(function(evt){
    evt.preventDefault();
    username = $('#username').val();
    password  = $('#password').val();
    console.log(username,password);
    $.ajax({
      type        : 'POST',
      data        : {username1:username,password1:password},
      dataType    : 'json',
      contentType : 'application/json',
      url         : '/admin/auth-login',
      success     : function(data){
                    console.log("fungsi login berjalan setelah auth-login");
                    window.location.href = "/admin/";
                    },
      error       : function(error){
                    console.log("fungsi login tidak berjalan setelah auth-login "+error.message);
                    } 
    });
  });
});
```

and this is the server side post function:

```js
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var favicon = require('static-favicon');
var logger = require('morgan');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var session = require('express-session');


//Controllers
var posts = require('./routes/posts');
var routes= require('./routes/routes');
var users = require('./routes/users');
var model = require ('../db-mysql');

var admin = express(); // the sub app

admin.use(session(
    {
    secret: 'AwiLelang',
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: true,
    cookie: {   
                secure: true,
                maxAge: 60000
            }
    }
));

admin.use(bodyParser.json());
admin.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));


// ==============================admin view engine setup==================================================//

admin.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
admin.set('view engine', 'ejs');

admin.get('/logout', users);
admin.get('/login', routes);
admin.post('/auth-login', users);
```

```js
// accept POST request on the admin posts index via posts/
users.post('/auth-login', function (req, res) {
    console.log('post login');
    if (!req.session.admin) {
        var data = {
            text: "SELECT * FROM user WHERE ? AND ?",
            placeholder: [{username: req.body.username}, {password: /*crypto.MD5(password1).toString()*/ req.body.password}],
        }
        model.mySQLQuery(data).then(function (result){
            console.log(result);
            if(result.length){
                req.session.admin=req.body.username;
                res.send('success');
                console.log('success login admin, session admin ke dashboard');
            }else{
                res.send('failure');
                console.log('gagal login admin');
            }
        }).catch(function(error){
            console.log('Error while executing SQL Query', err);
        });
    }else{
        res.redirect('/login');
    }
});
```

and this the Screenshot of console clientside:
[Admin Login Form undefined](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4DEUM.jpg)

Comment: You send a `username1` property but look for a `username` property. These names are not the same.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan, if using the same variabel it will be redundancy, and the username1 for variabel initiation

Comment: First of all, the word is spelled "variable", as I edited your question to fix. Please adjust how you spell the word. Secondly, you cannot have different property names if you expect to be able to access the property. You can have the same name for a property and the name of the variable you are setting the value to. Try it, you'll find that using `{username: username, password: password}` works just fine.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan, sorry my english isn't  fluent and thanks for the correction. i have try Ur suggestion, and it still ended "UNDEFINED"

Comment: "your", not "Ur" :). It's unclear what you mean by "ended "UNDEFINED"". Please [edit] your question and add exactly what line is showing `undefined` and what value you expect. See [ask] and how to create a [mcve].

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan, OMG i got grammar police :( ok thanks btw, what i want is the variable i post using ajax can be defined in serverside then processed to post function in serverside and can be used for admin authentication